# using html box value to js

Tags: javascript, html

i have a small school assinment using html and js
im trying to use the input from tht html "form" to js var,
but it dosnt work! 
the script worked fine when i used "prompt"

```
  <form>
        <input id="numbers" type="number"/>
    </form>
<script>
var num = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
var mid1 = 0;
var mid2 = 0;
var total = 0;
      for (var i = 1; i <=num; i+=2){
      mid1=i+mid1;}
      for (var j = 2; j <=num; j+=2){
          mid2=j+mid2;}
      total = mid1 - mid2;
alert(total);
</script>
```

Comment: Please, describe what "doesn't work" means exactly.

Comment: your js is executing before you even have a chance to put anything in the input box, use an event like onchange to execute your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your script is correct. you just need to trigger the script after you enter a value in the input box. otherwise it will be taken as 0 as soon as webpage loads.

```
<button onclick="doit()">click here</button>
<script>
function doit(){
var num = document.getElementById("numbers").value;

var mid1 = 0;
var mid2 = 0;
var total = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <=num; i+=2){
  mid1=i+mid1;}
  for (var j = 2; j <=num; j+=2){
      mid2=j+mid2;}
  total = mid1 - mid2;
alert(total);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to get the value from the input element as soon as the page is loaded. You're giving the user no time to use it!

The easiest way to fix this would be to use an input event handler that's attached to the input element.

Here's a solution:

```
<form>
    <input id="numbers" type="number"/>
</form>
<p id="output">
</p>
<script>
    function myFunc() {
        var num = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
        var mid1 = 0;
        var mid2 = 0;
        var total;
        for (var i = 1; i <= num; i += 2) {
            mid1 = i + mid1;
        }
        for (var j = 2; j <= num; j += 2) {
            mid2 = j + mid2;
        }
        total = mid1 - mid2;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = total;
    }
    document.getElementById("numbers").addEventListener("input", myFunc);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is being executed before you have input anything in the input box. You need your code to execute after you have entered something. Below i show using a click event to trigger the calculation

```
<form>
   <input id="numbers" type="number"/>
   <button id="calc">Calculate</button>
</form>
<script>
var btn = document.getElementById("calc");
btn.addEventListener("click",calc,false);
function calc(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var num = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
   var mid1 = 0;
   var mid2 = 0;
   var total = 0;
   for (var i = 1; i <=num; i+=2){
      mid1=i+mid1;
   }
   for (var j = 2; j <=num; j+=2){
      mid2=j+mid2;
   }
   total = mid1 - mid2;
   alert(total);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I beleived, you have issues inside loop that because "num" itself a value you have to run loop on it's length. Check the below updated code.

```
<form>
        <input id="numbers" type="number"/>
    </form>
<script>
var num = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
var mid1 = 0;
var mid2 = 0;
var total = 0;
      for (var i = 1; i <=num.length; i+=2){
      mid1=i+mid1;}
      for (var j = 2; j <=num.length; j+=2){
          mid2=j+mid2;}
      total = mid1 - mid2;
alert(total);
</script>
```

Comment: I think you are right. because getElementById will return onle one element. so there is no length property.

Comment: the type of the input is "number", so `num` should be a number, so his use of `num` is fine as long as he is actually putting in a number and not other text.